# no postback from asp:HiddenField in asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, events, updatepanel, postback, hiddenfield

I have the following situation:

.ascx:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.onoffswitch-checkbox').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
                $('#hf').val(1);
            else
                $('#hf').val(0);
        });
  });
 </script>

 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="hf"/>
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
              <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox">
              <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value="0"/>
              <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>  
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.vb:

```
Protected Sub hf_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles hf.ValueChanged

    label.Text = "something..."

End Sub
```

JS function changes the value of HiddenField after the CheckBox is checked or unchecked, but the ValueChaneged-Event of the HiddenField doesn't fire. I tryed with `asp:PostBackTrigger` - also no effect, can you see the error?

EDIT:

i tried also to declare the method in the control:

.ascx:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value="0" OnValueChanged="hf_ValueChanged"/>
```

.vb

```
 Protected Sub hf_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
        label.Text = "something"
 End Sub
```

no effect.

Comment: see firefox web console for error. and put it in Q.

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: Why you need hidden field? only for label text change? why not use checkbox event?

Comment: it is a short example for another problem, and there i need this HiddenField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after 2 days experimentation i found the following workaround. It is not very pretty, but it works like I want.

I am not sure, but i think the JS changes the value of the hidden field only on the client site and the server doesn't see the changes and so is the event not fired.

at first I called  manually a postback from js:

```
function changeHFValue(element) {
  if ($(element).is(":checked")) 
     $('#<%= hf.ClientID %>').val(1);
  else 
     $('#<%= hf.ClientID %>').val(0);
   __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', ''); //postback
}
```

ascx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" EnableViewState="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server"/>
        <input type='checkbox' onchange='changeHFValue(this);' id='cb'/>   
        <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
     </ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

now is the event fired because of postback, it goes in the method in .vb:

```
 Protected Sub hf_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles hf.ValueChanged
    If hf.Value Then
        label.Text = "something"
    Else
        label.Text = "something else"
    End If
 End Sub
```

the new problem was that the checkbox was always unchecked after postback, when the UpdatePanel was reloaded. The solution is to look at the HiddenField:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // bind your events here initially
   bind();
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); // Page request manager

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    // re-bind your events here after postback
    bind();
});

function bind() {
    if ($('#<%= hf.ClientID %>').val() == 1) 
       $('#cb').prop('checked', 'checked');
    else 
       $('#cb').prop('checked', '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UpdatePanel` will not work when you have `Response.Write("")` on event method. to change value of elements in `UpdatePanel`, try to use something like this:

```
hf.Value="something";
```

Comment: `Response.Write("")` was only one example. But i tried to change something in `UpdatePanel` it doesn't work too. I edited the quellcode in my question.

Answer (score 1):

dear you need to add the OnValueChanged attribute in Hidden Field and declare the method name, then it will fire click event.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" Value="0" OnValueChanged="hf_ValueChanged"/>


void hf_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Display the value of the HiddenField control.    
    string _strHDFValue = hf.Value;
    Response.Write("something...")    
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Yes found another missing thing, it will not not work unless you modify your JS code like this "$('#<%= hf.ClientID %>').val(1);" and do it on both if else blocks,we will be able to sort out issue. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately no effect

Comment: Try to follow this help tutorial, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: there is no `UpdataPanel` in this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

if not works after, add this attribute to `UpdatePanel` tag:

```
ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

See your `Page_Load` if you have any `Response.*`, if then, you should avoid it when load caused by `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my Page_Load on this test-Page is completely blank. I have no Responses anywhere.